# Can't display images sourced from GraphQL, error [gatsby-plugin-image] missing image prop

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

I'm trying to source content with images from Contentful into Gatsby but I failed to get images displayed.

I installed gatsby-transformer-sharp, gatsby-plugin-image, gatsby-plugin-sharp, gatsby-remark-images and gatsby-remark-images-contentful.

down below is a simple of my code

```
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

const Projects = ({ data }) => {
  const projects = data.projects.nodes
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo
        title={"Projects"}
        description={"Projects & Websites I've Developed"}
      />
      <div className={styles.portfolio}>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
        <h2>Projects & Websites I've Developed</h2>
        <div className={styles.projects}>
          {projects.map(project => (
            <Link
              to={"/projects/" + project.slug}
              key={project.id}
              className={styles.project}
            >
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(project.thumb)}
                alt={project.title}
              />
              <div className={styles.cardText}>
                <h3>{project.title}</h3>
                <p>{project.stack}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Projects

export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectsPage {
    projects: allContentfulProjects(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        key
        slug
        stack
        title
        thumb {
          gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

here what i got from GraphQL

```
{
  "data": {
    "projects": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "key": "project",
          "slug": "portfolio-website",
          "stack": "html - css - javascript",
          "title": "Portfolio Website",
          "thumb": [
            {
              "gatsbyImageData": {
                "images": {
                  "sources": [
                    {
                      "srcSet": "https://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=750&h=361&q=50&fm=webp 750w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1080&h=520&q=50&fm=webp 1080w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1366&h=658&q=50&fm=webp 1366w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1920&h=925&q=50&fm=webp 1920w",
                      "sizes": "100vw",
                      "type": "image/webp"
                    }
                  ],
                  "fallback": {
                    "src": "https://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1920&h=925&q=50&fm=png",
                    "srcSet": "https://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=750&h=361&q=50&fm=png 750w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1080&h=520&q=50&fm=png 1080w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1366&h=658&q=50&fm=png 1366w,\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/kj59ethbquzj/1qDaw8RjPxxhzjOehxHz1g/152307656408e0efcf7c907a59cd91a7/personal-portfolio-website.png?w=1920&h=925&q=50&fm=png 1920w",
                    "sizes": "100vw"
                  }
                },
                "layout": "fullWidth",
                "width": 1,
                "height": 0.4817708333333333,
                "placeholder": {
                  "fallback": "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

what it might be wrong with My code? need some help :)

Comment: Does the query return anything? What's the output of a `console.log(project)` inside the loop?

Comment: ya, the query is fine also I checked console.log(project) is working fine with displaying all entries, but I see in the console this error react.development.js:220 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `image` is marked as required in `GatsbyImage`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you print the `console.log(project)`? I mean, if you can't do `getImage(project.thumb)`is because maybe the `thumb` is not there in some position in the loop

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said in the comment section, I'd say that there's a position in `projects` that has no thumbnail defined (or not properly queried).

Try adding a condition wrapping the `GatsbyImage` display:

```
 {project.thumb && <GatsbyImage
        image={getImage(project.thumb)}
        alt={project.title}
      />}
```

That said, check in which `project` you have no thumbnail.

Comment: it's to weird bug, actually I have kept one project and one blog only in both of them dynamic images are not shown but other static images are working fine, I have add GraphQL query result as well so you can check if i did something wrong

Comment: Have you tried without using the `getImage` helper function? like `image={project.thumb.gatsbyImageData}`

Comment: ya i did. still not solved, I notice that some times the image show in graphQL and some times it's showing broken image !!? what could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried running a clean develop with `gatsby clean`? Does the develop process outputs any warning or error?

Comment: I think it's a bug from GraphQL itself, I did a 9 hour now debugging my code but i have a doubt it is from the GraphQL weird behaver when I check image on it's playground!!

Comment: I doubt it. GraphQL infers the nodes from your data so check that **all** your projects have a valid image.

Comment: As of now I have removed all My project pages and kept one project only, still I'm facing a hard time to get the image displayed !?

Comment: From what I see, you are using Contentful. Try downloading locally the assets using the `donwloadLocal: true` option

Comment: I tried to do so, after build, it creates an assets folder with an empty images folder

Comment: The problem seems to be on Contentful's side then

Comment: whatever I do changes in My code I only get this two errors, 1st one is this error in console  Failed prop type: The prop `image` is marked as required in `GatsbyImage`, but its value is `undefined`. , 2nd this error after building error [gatsby-plugin-image] missing image prop

Comment: I see when I console log (thumb) under GatsbyImageData the Image `sources: []` is an empty array? what could be the reason if i have only one page with one image? but in the `fallback` I can see the image `src`

Comment: Because the node is not being created properly. It looks like a source-plugin issue or Contentful's. Double-check that the image is published. If you are not fetching data, you can't display it.

Comment: I did published it and i did published a test project page included that image, even i tried to change the image with different sizes and formats ! actually I looked to seek some help from Contentful side hope the could help with a solution but still waiting for a revert from them.

Comment: Thank you Ferran Buireu as usual without your inputs and hints I couldn't figured it out, I really appreciate your kind work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out by

1- I removed all My content and images in Contentful CMS and create a fresh ones, It seemed there was a bug with sourcing Images into GraphQL where the Image src was always giving an empty array!!

2- Taking out `getImage` function and replace it with `<GatsbyImage image={project.thumb.gatsbyImageData} alt={project.title}/>`
,then `gatsby clean` to clear the .cashe and also triggered `clean cashe and rebuild`.

Now everything is works well.